# Scroll bar not showing when serving html from nx

Tags: html, monorepo, nrwl-nx

When I serve my html file from my nx mono repo, the scroll bar doesn't show. But when I open the same html file directly in the browser, the scroll bar works as normal. Is there some kind of setting that caused this? How can I make the scroll bar show like normal?

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>some text</div>
    <div>some text</div>
    ...
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have now added my code

Comment: Based on the code you show and assuming the view is shorter than the page in both cases, there's no particular reason why the scroll bar would not display. Use the browser's debugging console to see what the browser actually received in both cases. The `file://` version should be correct. I suspect the `localhost` version has something added.

Comment: do you have css link applied? if so check the network tab in each of these, it might be addressing problem of one of them